# Python program's "main()" not run on invocation

Tags: python

I'm new to learning Python and using Eclipse + PyDev. I can't seem to figure out why my program isn't running.

Here is my code:

```
def main():
    print("Testing")
    test1 = float(input("Test1: "))
    test2 = float(input("Test2: "))
    test3 = float(input("Test3: "))
    calculate_cost (test1, test2, test3)

def calculate_cost (test1, test2, test3):
    print("Testing")
```

I am assuming I am missing something in one or both of the functions to make this run properly.

Comment: You never called `main()` in your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is Python, not C/C++, `main()` is not the entry point to your program, you have to invoke the function manually. Just call it:

```
# your code
# ...
main()
```

If you want to prevent that your code is called when importing from other place, then you want to use:

```
# your code
# ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This question: [What does `if __name__ == “__main__”:` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) explains this last block.

Comment: It might be helpful to speak to *why* people do the `__name__ == '__main__'` bit, so it's not taken as a for-libraries-only thing. (For instance, being able to use static-analysis tools that import modules to analyze them).

Comment: Sure Charles, indeed I was looking for a SO question which explains it.

Comment: Yeah I am wondering that too.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike some other languages, there is no enforcement of the convention that a `main` function is called when a program is executed. In Python, you will have to do that manually. That means you will have to put a `main()` at the bottom of your script to make your `main` function execute.

A common pattern is to use the following:

```
if __name__ == '__main__`:
    main()
```

This will execute the `main` function when the script is run directly, but prevents its execution when the script is imported as a module somewhere else. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) for more details on that part.

Comment: Awesome thanks I didn't realize this was necessary.